# Pages "Send via email" doesn't work after upgrade

Tags: mail.app, email, sharing, pages

I just upgraded to Mountain Lion. So far, so good. Great upgrade. I also upgraded to Pages '09 latest version: 4.2.

"Send via email" option works on Pages **if and only if Mail.app is not running**. If **Mail.app** is already running, when I choose *PDF*, *Word* or *Pages* option to send the document to someone, it does nothing.

It's pretty annoying since it's a feature I used to use regularly.

Anyone else with the same issue? Any suggestions?

Comment: All of the actions in the Share > Send via Mail menu work for me even if Mail was open.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem. Postbox seems to be the answer. Removed it and now Send via Mail works again.

Comment: Can you please explain in more details why you think Postbox is the problem?

Comment: There was a problem. I've removed Postbox. Problem disappeared.